# Understanding of the given Hash function

Tags: hash, wireless, number-theory

I am implementing the below steps of an algorithm , i have implemented first 3 steps successfully , and i have doubt in the last step , i am unable  to understand the notation used to represent the hash function , what do i exactly need to pass as argument is the below given hash functions (last step).
Thanks in advance.
[image: ClSC Setup]

Comment: Are these stars or x's at the Z_p?  Does the paper say what it means?  Is it [the group of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_units#Group_of_units) or a string of numbers? What a about |M|, did the paper assign it a special meaning or does it simple mean: cardinality?

Comment: ya those are stars ,z*p means set of integers between 1 and p that are relatively prime to p .i.e two numbers say x,n are said to be relatively prime if gcd(x,n)=1 .

Comment: So it's the group of units. What about |M|?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hash functions given.  Only signatures.  You'd have to find hash functions which satisfy the signatures.

#### Some hints on how to read the signatures

Functions whose **domain** is given by a Cartesian product (e.g. A x B x C) work like this. Each factor is a set.  The function takes as many parameters as are factors involved in the Cartesian product.  The i'th parameter has to be in the i'th set of the Cartesian product.

Example

```
f: N x R x N -> R
```

Reads like

```
real f (int a, real b, int c)
```

The **range** can also be expressed by means of a Cartesian product in which case the function returns vectors of values from the corresponding sets.

Comment: Thank you very much .Can you give any links so i can understand it more.

Comment: Apart from the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), the [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) may interest you (because of the {0,1}* sets).